# Can I change the order of Eigen function?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

According to eigenvalue equation,

if $$A\vec{v} == \lambda \vec{v}$$
Then the eigenvector of $A$ is $\vec{v}$, and the eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$.

I am wondering that

if $\vec{v}A == \vec{v} \lambda$, is $\vec{v}$ still the eigenvector of $A$ and is $\lambda$ still the eigenvalue of $A$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $\vec{v}A$? If $A$ is not a $1\times 1$ matrix, than the multiplication is undefined.

Comment: What you can say is that, taking transposes, we have $v^T A^T = \lambda v^T$. As eminem says, the product $vA$ in general is undefined.

Comment: It's not good practice to say "the eigenvector of $A$ is $\vec{v}$" or "the eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$", since in general $A$ may have many eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Instead, you should say "$\vec{v}$ is *an* eigenvector of $A$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$", or something like that.

Comment: I try to use $\vec{v}A$ to present the inner product of $\vec{v}$ and A. After reading the reply of eminem and Qiaochu. I totally figure out what I am trying to ask. I am learning an approach to get eigen vector of A. @eminem

Comment: Here is the approach:

A is a 3x3 matrix, $\vec{v}$ is a 1x3 matrix. 
`for i in range(25):
  v' = v.dot(A)
  v = v'`
If the Euclidean distance between v and v' converges to 0, then $v' = v = vA$. Then we found the eigenvector of A for which the corresponding eigenvalue is 1.


After reading the answer of Qiaochu, the transpose matrix of v' should be the eigenvector of A for which the corresponding eigenvalue is 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, eminem, Qiaochu Yuan. And I will pay attention to what you said, diracdeltafunk